# Could you explain the 4th and 5th lines of this code?

Tags: python

I want to recreate a Python code from a colleague's old script. I could  not understand what kind of programming language is used in the script; I would appreciate if someone could explain the 4th and 5th lines of the code! I understood at first glance that these lines integrate the angle from 0 to 2/π, right? how could one formulate these lines in Python code, I tried with a for Loop but I failed, and I simply used the Numpy.arange to generate angles from 0 to 2/pi; but the final result is a bit deviated from the original code's result.

```
let lambda = 450; n1 = 2.45; n2 = 1.5
let d = 1
set data 1000
let x=1;X=x++
let alpha = X*pi/(2*(data-1))
let arc = min(n1*sin(alpha)/n2,1)
let beta = asin(arc)
```

Comment: What language is this written in? What is the file extension used in the name of the file that contains this code?

Comment: The file extension of the script is .ft, but I do not have any information about  the language.

Comment: Is [this](https://filext.com/file-extension/FT) about accurate?

Comment: thanks, it is accurate, but I dont know how to execute this code .  how could it look like if one writes the 4th and 5th lines in py with a  for loop?

Answer (score 2):

From what I can gather:

Line 3: Setting the variable `data` to 1000

Line 4: Actually two line's (separated by semi-colon) is creating an integer called `x` and setting it to 1 and then incremented as seen by the `x++`

I have no idea what language this is so I might not be right. It looks like a combination of Python, C++ and a little JavaScript thrown in for good luck

Edit: You mentioned it was an ".ft" file so here what i found on [fileinfo](https://fileinfo.com/extension/ft):

> File used by Edgecam, a Computer-Aided Manufacturing (CAM) program used for designing manufacturing parts and generating Numerical Control (NC) code to machine them; contains geometric information in an XML format describing a range of similar machinable features and their common attributes.

> More Information: Feature templates are used as a common starting point to identify and control the machining of machinable features on manufacturing parts.

Answer (score 1):

The programming language from the syntax is javascript. From looking at the code line 4: `let x = 1; X=x++` is setting the value `1` into x and incrementing it and saving the answer into the variable `X`.

Comment: thanks, how it could look like if lines 4 and 5  are written in py?   ' data = 1000
x = 1
X=0
for i in range(data):
    X +=x
    alpha = X*pi/(2*(i-1))
   '

Comment: @Avral In Python you don't need to add the `set` to define a variable. Also to increment can be done using this: `x += 1`